# Jackson ObjectMapper unreachable in try catch

Tags: java, jackson

I have a weird issue with Jackson ObjectMapper.

What I'm trying to do (please advise me a better approach if you want) is to parse the result of a REST call. That result is a `String` and I want to parse it with `ObjectMapper` to populate a POJO. But the flow doesn't even enters the `try catch` section.  Below is the `controller` code I'm using :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData(Model model){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();     

        ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.exchange("http://api.aelf.org/v1/informations/2017-09-20/romain",
                                             HttpMethod.GET,
                                             UserAgent.setUserAgentInHttpHeader(), String.class);

        try{
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(res.getBody());
            JsonNode name = root.path("semaine");

            model.addAttribute("name", name.asText());

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                           
        return "myView";
    }
```

What is happening when I debug this is that I see all variables, including `res` and the content of the REST call in JSON format BUT none of the varialbles in the `try` is present. Consequently, the model is never populated with any `name` data.

Comment: when you step into the try statement, those vars will be in scope. put a break point in the exception, and step into this, verify res.getBody() is giving you want you expect in the watch. and the mapper constructor can get moved out of the try, the cstr will not fail

Comment: @Tim Yes Tim. I put a break in `try` and in `catch` it stopped in `try`... `root` got what I want. I think I only failed reaching the data  for `name`.. The JSON structure of `root` is `{"info":{"semaine" : "data1", "other_field":"other_data"}}...I'm going to look on it...

Comment: @Tim. Problem solved... `when you step into the try statement, those vars will be in scope. put a break point in the exception, and step into this` you've helped me...Thanks

Comment: Cool. Ok, added as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you step into the try statement, those vars will be in scope. Continue stepping into the try area.

Also, putting a break point on the exception can be helpful, in case it falls through.